# Bundle ractive with ractive-load through Rollup

Tags: npm, bundle, ractivejs, rollupjs, ractive-load

What is the correct way to import **ractive** and **ractive-load** to my **rollup** project? npm or github?

Currently I am using **npm** to install each one:

```
npm install --save-dev ractivejs/ractive
```

And

```
npm install --save-dev ractivejs/ractive-load
```

And I'm using `rollup-plugin-commonjs` with `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` to corretly bundle them (*rollup.config.js* in the end of the question):

```
import Ractive from 'ractive';
import load from 'ractive-load';
...
```

But it seems that ractive-load also imports other modules in its code, causing this error:

`Error parsing /home/.../node_modules/rcu/src/make.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (2:0) in /home/.../node_modules/rcu/src/make.js`

How can I correctly use Rollup and which are the right sources for this case (npm or github)?

---

Here is my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  entry: 'src/main.js',
  plugins: [

  nodeResolve({
        jsnext: true,
        main: true,
        browser: true,
    }),

    commonjs({
        sourceMap: false
  }),

  // uglify()

  ],
  format: 'iife',
  moduleName: 'Altiva',
  dest: 'altiva.js'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ractive-load` is intended to "read" `link` tags in the browser and then do AJAX requests for the component file, then it uses a library called [`rcu`](https://github.com/ractivejs/rcu) to convert the component files into usable javascript components.

What you need is a utility (that uses `rcu` or does equivalent work) to turn your component files into javascript files that you can run during build process then hand-off to `rollup`. Fortunately, it looks like there is a rollup plugin [`rollup-plugin-ractive`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-ractive) designed to do just that:

```
rollup({
  entry: 'src/main.js',
  plugins: [
    ractive({
      // By default, all .html files are compiled
      extensions: [ '.html', '.ract' ],

      // You can restrict which files are compiled
      // using `include` and `exclude`
      include: 'src/components/**.html'
    })
  ]
}).then(...)
```

There's also list of some of the available loaders [here](https://github.com/ractivejs/component-spec#available-loaders), among them are "plain vanilla js" variants as well.

Comment: What I really needed was rcu! I am building my own loader now, and it is the perfect library for waht I am doing! Thank you so much!